# How to install MyODBC in Windows 7?

Tags: mysql, windows-7, odbc

The downloaded installers from MySQL don't work - ie no mysql driver appears in the ODBC manager thing.

I've downloaded the mysql-connector-odbc-noinstall-5.1.6-win32 version, copied myodbc5.dll and myodbcS.dll to c:\windows\system32

```
C:\dump\bin>myodbc-installer -d -a -n "MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver"  -t "DRIVER=
c:\windows\system32\myodbc5.dll;SETUP=c:\windows\system32\myodbc5S.dll"
Success: Usage count is 2
```

.. looks good but still no driver appears in the ODBC manager thing  .

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are on a 32 bit Windows 7, right?

Comment: (from the website link mentioned below) The command you need to run is c:\windows\syswow64\odbcad32.exe

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear whether you're on a 32 or 64 bit Windows, but If you are 64, it probably makes sense that the installation works out, but the driver doesn't turn up in the dialog.

Check out this article: [**Installing MyODBC 3.51 on Windows 7 x64**](http://www.getdowntonight.co.uk/2009/11/installing-myodbc-3-51-on-windows-7-x64/)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Pekka, you're right (someone else just told me) there's another ODBC manager - \SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe which does show the installed driver. The winX64 MSI installer download works.

Thanks to all for the site.

John.

Comment: Just got me too, two versions of the same program only one of which works, more of my life sacrificed on Bill Gates Altar.

Answer (score 0):

The nasty thing about this is that Control Panel will show an item entitled "ODBC (32-bit)", but this actually invokes the 64-bit ODBC administration in 64-bit Windows (irresponsively located at `c:\windows\system32\odbccp32.cpl`).

To get to the 32-bit ODBC administration, either use `odbcad32.exe` as mentioned by other posters, or invoke `control c:\windows\syswow64\odbccp32.cpl`.

Answer (score 0):

mysql-connector-odbc-noinstall-5.1.6-win32.zip  version can only be installed on a 32bit system, see [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-installation-binary-windows-dll.html)

It states that:

> The following instructions only work for 32-bit Windows systems. If you have a 64-bit Windows system, use the MSI installer, which installs both the 32-bit and 64-bit drivers to the correct locations.